# Sequence Diagram generator for Ruby or Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uml, sequence-diagram

Is there an application / gem / anything that can generate sequence diagram for Ruby method? I need to generate some sequence diagrams for a Ruby on Rails project and I cannot find anything that can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know about gems [rails-erd](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd)  or [railroady](https://github.com/preston/railroady). which can generate UML diagrams for a rails application.
Add any one to your Gemfile and generate a uml diagram

```
gem "rails-erd"
```

In terminal run

```
ubuntu:~/rails-app$ bundle install
ubuntu:~/rails-app$ bundle exec erd
```

or

```
gem 'railroady'
```

In terminal run

```
ubuntu:~/rails-app$ bundle install
ubuntu:~/rails-app$ railroady -o models.dot -M 
ubuntu:~/rails-app$ dot -Tpng models.dot > models.png
```

Comment: I used railroady to generate diagrams for models and it works great! But now, I need something that can generate sequence diagrams for some methods, like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/CheckEmail.svg/440px-CheckEmail.svg.png

Comment: i dont have any idea.